# libGDX connect two actors with line

Tags: java, android, graph, libgdx, actor

I have to create 2 images and connect them with line. When I move one actor obviously correct end of line must fallow my actor. I know, that I can use `ShapeRenderer` and redraw that line every time, but is this the best idea?

```
ShapeRenderer sr = new ShapeRenderer();
    sr.setColor(Color.RED);
    sr.setProjectionMatrix(viewport.getCamera().combined);

    sr.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    sr.rectLine(vertex1.getCenterX(), vertex1.getCenterY(),
            vertex2.getCenterX(), vertex2.getCenterY(), 10);
    sr.end();
```

I have already created two actors and manage drag event. Now I have to draw that line. It should looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the shaperender suits your style I don't see why that would be a bad idea?

If you draw the lines behind the actors you simply have to draw from the center of actor 1 to 2. Otherwise you have to calculate where to start. Something like this pseudo code:

```
//Subtract vectors and normalize to get direction
direction = origin1.sub(origin2);
direction.nor();

//Add the radius in the correct direction from the origin.
startPoint = origin2.add(direction * actorRadius);
endPoint = origin1.add(direction.rotate(180) * actorRadius);
```

Be careful of working with vectors like that. Chaining like above will change the original vector if you do not use `vector.cpy()`. So if you still need the original origins you have to do `direction = origin1.cpy().sub(origin2);` now direction holds a copy of the vector.

Comment: using shaperenderer is generally bad idea due to performance - it will increase your batch **flush()** calls so be careful with this. And of course do not create new instance of shaperenderer in update loop!

Comment: @m.antkowicz hmm, didn't know that. Only used it for debugging myself and had a ton of lines in my previous app. Never noticed performance issues.

Comment: lucky you ;) it of course depends on count of used atlases etc - but generally be aware of it